# Both javaw.exe *32 and javaw.exe runs in process manager

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, javaw

I am developing a portal based on Liferay and I use Eclipse as IDE. I am running a 64 bit windows 7 with 8gb RAM ddr2 and AMD Athlon II X2 255 3.10 GHz. My computers freezes some time when I run service builder or when I want to open an xml file in eclipse. I checked the Process Manager from Task Manager and I have seen that I have two javaw processes running , jaxaw.exe*32 and javaw.exe.Is this normal. If this is a problem can you help me to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One process is for *Eclipse itself* and the other one is for your *application*. And no that is not a problem.

Comment: try killing that process and see if eclipse closes. IMHO it is the process created by eclipse.exe

Answer (score 0):

That's not problem. In most cases, this is caused by two different jvm processes, one for 32 bit jvm, another for 64bit. It's rarely to see that one process can cause this issue, in fact, I have never seen in my past 15 years java career.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have seen this in my past 3 month of java career.